# composer network install it's not working

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying setup HyperLedger fabric 1.1 on IBM cloud.I'm follwing this is link " https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org "..In this link 7th step " Installing the Hyperledger Composer business network onto the Hyperledger Fabric peer nodes  "..I'm  running this command **composer network install -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network -a tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna**..It's not working that command..

here is screenshot :-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p84f.png)

please let me...
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally request support from the IBM Cloud Portal (link here -> https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/ibmblockchain_support.html#ibmblockchain_support) - you can also see ANSWERS here on the IBM site -> https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/261/blockchain.html

If using its Enterprise plan my guess is that you should be using this guide for 0.16.x of Composer -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org (to match your Composer version) - the tutorial link you provided is for version 0.19.x of Composer which has a different command sequence and probably explains the 'syntax' issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion...I followed as u suggested but after this command `composer card import -f PeerAdmin@fabric-network.card` I am getting this error msg.   **Error: No connection type provided, probably because the connection profile has no 'x-type' property defined.
Command failed**...To bring in your notice i am doing set up of version 1.0 please suggest accordingly. My composer is version `v0.17.4`.

Comment: That 'x-type' error is caused by trying to import a v0.16 format card into a newer version of composer.  If you are using Enterprise Plan you need Composer v0.16.  If you are using Starter Plan you need v0.18.1 - but that will change soon to v0.19.  As suggested above you should raise a ticked with IBM Cloud.

Comment: @RThatcher I have setup **composer-rest-server** successfully.Composer version **0.19.5** , node version **8.9.4** and Fabric **v1.1**

Answer (score 0):

If you are only installing hyperledger now, be aware that some of the commands have been removed in hyperedger 19.0 which is the latest version as of today, refer to this [link](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases/tag/v0.19.0) for more information on removed and new commands.